# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python-venv, mediapipe, pyvenv

I am trying to pip install medipipe in my virtual environment and I am getting the following error:

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\fernanad\Documents\tensorflow object detection\TFODCourse\tfod\Lib\site-packages\cv2\cv2.pyd'

What I have already tried:

- pip install mediapiepe
- pip install mediapiepe --user (ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.)
- pip3 install mediapiepe
- pip3 install mediapiepe --user (ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.)
- run the command prompt as administrator and/or pip install mediapipe --user

Specs:

- Windows 10
  -Python 3.11

Thank you in advance for your help!!!

What I have already tried:

- pip install mediapiepe
- pip install mediapiepe --user (ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.)
- pip3 install mediapiepe
- pip3 install mediapiepe --user (ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.)
- run the command prompt as administrator and/or pip install mediapipe --user